# Using a Windows computer as a Bluetooth input device for another computer/device

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, android, hid

Ok, I realize this is a totally backwards use-case but I've got to imagine it's technically possible.
I have an android tablet (Acer A500) that I use at work to get to personal email and IM since I can use it to connect to a nearby coffee shop wifi AP. It works fine, but I would love to be able to use a regular keyboard with it.  Obviously, I know that Android 3.1 supports bluetooth and USB keyboards and mice, but I'd rather not add another one to my desk (or have to buy one for that matter).

My first though was if there was a Synergy client for android (which would be totally great), but that wouldn't work anyways because they would have to be on the same network and are definitely not.  I have an app for the tablet (blueputdroid pro) that lets me use the tablet as a HID keyboard for just about anything else, so I'm hoping there's a way to just do the opposite... maybe the bluetooth on my desktop appear to the tablet as a HID device and then be able to (probably through some app window) redirect keyboard output to the tablet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever get something working for this? I'm trying to do a similar thing, but controlling an iPad. "Across" doesn't work for iOS (because it didn't even have a mouse), but iOS13 adds supports for Bluetooth mouse so what you're describing might be possible now, even for iPad.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but since there still seems to be interest, here's one solution. Not really bluetooth, but if **WiFi** works, you can use [KDE Connect](https://kdeconnect.kde.org/), among other apps, that will let you use your computer keyboard as input to phones and other devices (and vice-versa). It's FOSS and cross-platform

Answer (score 8):

Try [Across](http://www.acrosscenter.com/), unfortuantly for me my phone was lacking support.

[image: across-pc-as-bluetooth-mouse.png]

Answer (score 3):

The question explicitly specifies *"Windows computer"*, so for this *exact* use case, my answer doesn't help.

(I am posting it anyway, because in the same way that I found this question, even though I was looking for a solution using a *linux* machine, probably other people in the same situation will find the answer.)

There's: https://github.com/kcolford/hidclient

> The hidclient program makes a Bluetooth® technology equipped computer appear as a Bluetooth® keyboard and mouse device to other machines.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that ShareKM would work for you.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.liveov.skm&hl=en

It works over USB, wifi or Bluetooth. I have not personally used it via Bluetooth but both USB and Wifi work well. It effectively extends your keyboard and mouse to your tablet/phone in a very similar way to synergy.

There are others that will work via other connection types.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xdevelop.rmp&hl=en

The full version of that will bridge between your devices via the internet and you don't need to install anything on your local machine (if you don't have admin rights for example) as it works through the browser. It is a slightly less slick solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Some Android devices seem to support Bluetooth HID as sources. With an app such as [Remote Numpad](https://github.com/theolizard/remote-numpad) (on F-Droid), the Android device becomes just another Bluetooth HID device.

If your Android does not support that Bluetooth functionality yet, Remote Numpad also supports sending the keystrokes over Wi-Fi. There is a companyon app provided for the receiver.