# Can I make my PC act as a Bluetooth human interface device?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, bluetooth, wii

My question is similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/312366/using-a-windows-computer-as-a-bluetooth-input-device-for-another-computer-device), but more broad, and the other has no answers.

Is it possible to make a PC (either Windows or Ubuntu) connect via Bluetooth to another device as though the PC is a Human Interface Device? In this particular case, I want to try to make my Wii think that my computer is a Wiimote.

Comment: Similarly, I want to control my PS3 via my laptop.  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16506/can-i-remotely-control-my-ps3-with-my-laptop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I googled for a while and I think you are out of luck. This is possible, but apparently no one has done it.

If you want to use your laptop's keyboard or mouse with another computer, you can use [hidclient](http://anselm.hoffmeister.be/computer/hidclient/index.html.en) for linux.
As for the Wii, there are [many libraries](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote/Library) that allow you to use the Wiimote to control your computer, but none to do what you pretend. You would have to implement Wiimote's client protocol by hand.

If you are interested in writing it, the [WiiBrew wiki](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote) has lots of information on the Wiimote. I have also found some info about Wiimote emulation at www.wiili.org (which is down, but can be accessed via [web archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20090418040040/http://www.wiili.org/Wii_bluetooth_specs#Wiimote_Emulation)): someone wrote a little program to change your computer's HID descriptor and communicate with the Wii, but there are no further developments.

Comment: Thanks, this info is great. I am just holding off on accepting to see if anything else shows up.

Answer (score 2):

Because this thing I have described does not seem to exist, I have started a [project](https://github.com/murgatroid99/connect-pc-to-wii) on GitHub to create it. I have started with the code posted at nmat's [second link](http://web.archive.org/web/20090418040040/http://www.wiili.org/Wii_bluetooth_specs#Wiimote_Emulation).