# Using laptop keyboard as wireless bluetooth keyboard

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth

Example 1 : More like [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/), but Synergy works over the Internet. I was thinking of something over Bluetooth.

Example 2 : This has been implemented in an [Android app](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/use-your-pc-as-your-android-keyboard-with-pcbtkeyboard/).
But in the Android app, there's a dedicated application for PC(Java) in addition to the app.

But **normal Bluetooth keyboards don't run dedicated software, you can just use it out of the box.**

So can't we just make a laptop keyboard act as a Bluetooth keyboard?

PS: Everybody says buy a wireless keyboard; they're very cheap. But if software can do the task, why buy hardware? Also, I want to check how well Bluetooth works on my old Nokia e63, so this is of temporary use.

Comment: Whats wrong with the question? Is it logically incorrect?

Comment: It is badly worded. You are asking if it is possible to share a computers keyboard via bluetooth. Scrap the part about malware/virus or leave it as an example.

Comment: Also, there are answers in https://superuser.com/questions/312366/using-a-windows-computer-as-a-bluetooth-input-device-for-another-computer-device.

Answer (score 2):

On Macs, the application type2phone offers exactly this functionality. 
As long as this application is active (i.e. not in the background), all keyboard input is sent to a paired iPhone (or in fact, any device that supports input from bluetooth keyboards). No software whatsoever needs to be installed on the target device, since all it sees is a generic bluetooth keyboard.
Actually i have been looking for a windows pendant to type2phone, but haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 1):

If a virus/malware/whatever is intercepting keystrokes, then changing the method of connection to the PC is irrelevant.  USB, wireless, Bluetooth, PS2, AT, etc, it doesnt matter.

Comment: You seriously thought that I wanted to modify a malware and send the keystroke via bluetooth? I just gave an example of malware. I was thinking of a proper software, and not changing the method of connecting of malware to PC(is it even possible?)

Answer (score 1):

[Across](http://www.acrosscenter.com) can do this. It supports sharing keyboards attached to a Windows or macOS machine to anything that supports Bluetooth, including Windows, macOS, iOS, and Android devices.

I don't have much experience with it. I actually came across both that software and this question today, trying to do something similar myself. I hope it works well for both of us :).

If you use the trial, note the [somewhat unorthodox trial limitations](https://download.acrosscenter.com/), which can appear to be bugs at first glance:

> The trial version only works without any limit for 30 minutes after computer starts. After the 30 minutes, mouse works without any limit, but when you input keyboard to a client device with the trial version, you will be unable to input the ‘Q’, ‘W’, ‘E’, ‘I’, ‘O’, ‘P’ keys of a keyboard (the ‘A’, ‘Z’, ‘E’, ‘I’, ‘O’, ‘P’ keys of a French keyboard) to the device. Also, the length of the clipboard text that can be synchronized between devices is limited.

Comment: That is an innovative free trial limitation. Lets you demo while also making it useless

Answer (score 0):

The method that I use is to run vnc server on the tablet and vnc viewer on the keyboard-laptop. You can use Bluetooth to connect the 2 devices together using the Personal Area Network feature. This solution works only if you have Windows, Mac OS or Linux on the device being controlled. See http://www.realvnc.com for details.

The graphics is going to be disappointing, but at least you can use your keyboard and mouse from your laptop.

There are also other vnc software such as tightvnc and ultravnc but I didn't try them.