# Control Android from Chromebook/PC, remote keyboard/mouse

Tags: android, remote, chromebook

I have a Fire TV Stick and would like to use a spare laptop (Chromebook or PC) to function as a wireless keyboard. There are a few applications that perform screen mirroring, which is overkill. I'm looking for the opposite of [Unified Remote](https://www.unifiedremote.com/), not necessarily a screen mirroring application.

[One way to solve](https://superuser.com/q/312366/31240): can a PC or Chromebook be configured to behave as a bluetooth keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

[scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) may allow you to control your Android device (Fire TV) remotely. It does also provide screen mirroring as a side effect and requires adb debugging enabled.

[image: Screenshot]