# How to use the PC as a Bluetooth peripheral keyboard to Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want a software to use instead of USB hub to Android to play free fire. I don't want to buy a USB hub and I have a little idea that if I could emulate a bluetooth keyboard signal from pc to my phone and my phone receive the signal as a bluetooth peripheral keyboard.
Is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a Windows computer as a Bluetooth input device for another computer/device](https://superuser.com/questions/312366/using-a-windows-computer-as-a-bluetooth-input-device-for-another-computer-device)

Comment: FYI (slightly off topic) if you have a usb gamepad, it probably will "just work" with your android